# sbt: disable testing in certain sub-modules

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest, sbt-crossproject

My project has several module, like

- server (JVM)
- sharedJVM
- sharedJS
- client (JS)

At the moment testing does only work for the JVM modules.

What I can do is:

`sbt sharedJVM/test server/test`

What I want do is:

`sbt test`

I couldn't find a Setting to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of `aggregatedProjects` as below:

```
lazy val aggregatedProjects: Seq[ProjectReference] = Seq(
  server,
  sharedJVM
)

lazy val root = project
  .in(file("."))
  .aggregate(aggregatedProjects: _*)
```

Once you do this, then whatever command you execute at root project level will be propagated to aggregated projects.
Which means by running `sbt test` will execute `sbt server/test` and `sbt sharedJVM/test`

Comment: thanks - this works - only downside is that clean does not clean the modules `client` and `sharedJS`